# SQL Group By and window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I am struggling a little bit with an SQL Statement and was hoping if someone would be willing to point me in the right direction.

Below is a picture of my table:

[image]

As you can see here I have a column called 'State'. Basically I want to group all 'State' associated with a particular BuildID and display them in an extra column on my SQL output.

I am close but not quite there.

In the next picture below is an example of the statement I have used to try and achieve this:

[image]

As you can see here, it has done SUM and added the TotalTime and created the extra columns I require. However instead of grouping it all into one record, it has created 2 extra lines per BuildID. One with the value for the 'Running' state, another record for the value State of 'Break' and another record that contains the value 0 on both States.

Now what I want it to do is group it into one record for each BuildID. Like the picture I have added below:

[image]

The above image is how I want the records displayed. But the problem is I have added the WHERE [State] = Running, which I know is wrong but was just using this as an example. As you can see the 'Break' column has no value.

I hope this makes sense and was hoping if someone could point me in the right direction?

Here is an example on SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b6b9/2

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have refined the sql a bit, here you go:

```
SELECT BuildID,Product, Program, 
  sum(CASE WHEN State = 'Running' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS Running
  , sum(CASE WHEN State = 'Break' THEN cast(TotalTime as INT) ELSE 0 END) AS Breakt
FROM Line1Log
GROUP BY BuildID,Product, Program
```

Please check [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e460a/10)

Not sure if i am missing something :-), but the solution looks pretty straight forward. Let me know.

Answer (score 3):

move your SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY...) out from CASE

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b6b9/11)

```
select BuildID, Product, Program, Sum(Running) Running, Sum([Break]) [Break]
from (
    SELECT Distinct BuildID, Product, Program, 
    Sum(Case when [State]='Running' Then TotalTime Else 0 END) OVER (Partition by [State], [BuildID]) Running,
    Sum(Case when [State]='Break' Then TotalTime Else 0 END) OVER (Partition by [State], [BuildID]) [Break]

    From Line1Log) T
group by BuildID, Product, Program
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however this gives me the same result as the images I have added above, it adds these into columns but displays them all as separate records

Comment: Strange. It must work fine. Could you build SQL fiddle for your data and request?

Comment: Also perfect :) thanks again for your help, this has helped me out so much, I really appreciate your time and effort :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Everything else is ok, why are you grouping all columns?, Try this,

```
Select BuidId,Product,program,Sum(Running),Sum(Break)
(......
.....
......) as T
group by BuidId,Product,program
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this does not work for me as the columns for Running and Break are not created yet. These extra columns are created after the select statement.